# Different time in two date columns after inserting a new record using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, datetime, timestamp, generated

I have Entity with two columns that contains date:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Document {
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateUtils.DD_MM_YYYY_HH_MM)
    Generated(value = GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "created_datetime")
    private Timestamp createdDateTime;

    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = DateUtils.DD_MM_YYYY_HH_MM)
    @Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    @Column(name = "last_updated_datetime")
    private Timestamp lastUpdatedDateTime;

    //....
}
```

When I save new Document object, this two columns in database have the same time. But sometimes they have different time around 10...200 milliseconds. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is generating new instances of Timestamp for these fields as it encounters each individual field, which could happen microseconds apart. It's not unexpected that there would be some variation between these fields though 200 milliseconds is alot.

If this is an issue that needs to be resolved then instead of using the @Generated annotation one of the following could be done:

1. Create a Hibernate Interceptor that looks for these fields and if found assigns the same Timestamp instance to 'createdDatetime' and 'lastUpdatedDateTime' onSave, or only generate an new Timestamp for 'lastUpdatedDatetime' onFlushDirty. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html
2. Similary to the above, use JPA callbacks @PrePersist and @PreUpdate instead of a Hibernate Interceptor. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html